# Foreign pre-paid Minecraft cards in Europe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can pre-paid Minecraft cards that were bought in the USA be redeemed in Denmark? It's a different currency so I'm not sure how this works internationally.

Comment: It should. Minecraft's price is adjusted for different currencies. If you do it strategically, you might save a few cents.

Answer (score 1):

There is no region lock in the PC (Java) version of Minecraft.

The Minecraft gift cards for PC are completely region-free. For Console versions things might be different, though.